# Do the properties of two streams flowing into an engine add together when they mix?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

Let's say I have two stream supplys that have separate mass flow rates, enthalpies, and velocities that flow into an engine. Upstream of the engine's inlet, the two streams mix to form one stream that flows into the engine inlet. Do the properties of the streams add together when they mix like the mass flow rate adds together?

Comment: It depends on whether the entropy of mixing is negligible, I suppose, and whether the streams mix into a homogenous fluid. Can you be more specific about the engine, like the actual meaning of the enthalpies? If you are talking about a heat engine operating with only a slightly warmer input than output, the answer might be very different than an internal combustion engine with huge chemical energies released internally.

Comment: thanks for the help Ron, but all I know is that it's an engine with 2 streams flowing in and 2 streams flowing out; it was a homework question that I needed clarification on the concept.
Also, I appreciate the help Georg, not. When I said "properties", I meant flow rates, enthalpies, and velocities. Exactly as I stated in the question. I am taking a Thermodynamics course in college. If you're going to help, then actually help instead of bashing people for not using the correct terminology when they are in a hurry. I thought someone could figure that out what I was trying to say in the question

Comment: @Greg: if it was a homework question, I would guess they are most likely asking you about entropy of mixing, which is a common course topic in thermodynamics. The flow rates will add, the velocities will combine so that the velocity times pipe cross section adds up, and the enthalpies will have a mixing entropy correction, so that mixed fluids will cool down. For homework questions, you might want to give the exact phrasing, and the topics covered in the class.

Comment: @RonMaimon, thanks for the help. I didn't think I should say it was a homework question because it seems like people are less inclined to help when someone says it's a homework question. Feel free to answer my other questions I post because I have tons of them at the moment because I am self teaching myself thermodynamics and fluid mechanics.

Comment: If it's a homework question, you most certainly should say so. It's not that we're less willing to help with homework questions, but you may have noticed that some people just post their homework problems verbatim and hope someone here will provide the solution. We don't do that. For a question like this one which is asked in a "conceptual" manner, identifying it as homework simply means that we'll answer it a little more generally than we would otherwise. (P.S. I deleted an inappropriate comment above)

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky I really appreciate the help. I think I will start doing that from now on. I am learning both fluid mechanics and thermodynamics on my own without any help. So the question's I'm asking aren't homework per say, but they are problems from the book. Most of the time I have more than half of the problem done and I just need some ideas about where to go next.

Comment: I've actually been thinking: the way you're asking your questions, they're general enough that they don't really count as "homework questions." Rather, they're general conceptual physics questions that just happen to be motivated by homework problems. That's a good thing - what you're doing is exactly what we wish most people who come here looking for homework help would do. It also means that the "homework" tag doesn't need to be applied to your questions, at least not the way you've asked them. (The tag is more for people who feel the need to post their specific homework questions.)

Comment: I do realize that this makes it kind of tough to decide when you need to use the "homework" tag and when you don't... when it doubt, it doesn't hurt to use it at first, and we can always take it off later.

Comment: I've seen from past forums that the more a question applies to a homework, the less people will be inclined to help when little work is shown by the asker. So I am just used to asking general questions that can be applied to more homework problems if I have them again. When I post in the homework section, is it ok if I put the problem verbatim but then show a substantial attempt at a solution to get some ideas from people?

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky  would you mind looking at my problem about gas flowing into an initially evacuated tank. I have almost all of it done but I am stuck at one part and I can't figure out how to get past it

Comment: Extensive properties add, intensive properties average by weight of whatever physical quantity they are intensive in.